Responsive Nav Bar HTML Issue
I am new to HTML and am trying to get the nav bar headings to shift under the logo when the screen size goes below the specified number of pixels - https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_responsive - sort of like this
(The CSS will eventually be moved to an external style sheet). How can I alter the code accordingly?


/* General styles */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #005d6c;
}


/* Navigation styles */

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  text-align: right;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* Align the ul to the right */
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* Add padding from the right edge */
}

.Logo {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  /* Move the logo up by 20 pixels */
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* Move the logo 20 pixels to the left */
}


/* Dropdown menu styles */

.dropbtn {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Adjustments for smaller screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 718px) {
  nav {
    text-align: center;
    /* Center align the navigation links */
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
    /* Hide the navigation links */
  }
  .Logo {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .image-container {
    margin-top: 150px;
    /* Adjusted margin for smaller screens */
  }
  .text-overlay {
    font-size: large;
    /* Adjusted font size for smaller screens */
  }
  .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    /* Make the dropdown button visible */
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    text-align: center;
    /* Center align the dropdown links */
  }
}
<nav>
  <div class="Logo">
    <a href="HomePage.html">
      <img src="Icon.png" alt="Logo" class="Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Donate.html">Donate Now</a></li>
    <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="OurCampaigns.html">Our Campaigns</a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropbtn">&#9776;</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="Donate.html">Donate Now</a>
        <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="OurCampaigns.html">Our Campaigns</a>
        <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>




Try using flexbox on your ul element in your media query, something like this:
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


CodePen example here.
